# Detecting when user presses the red x

Tags: c#

Super new to C#, but ran into a little roadblock on my most recent project.  I have a couple window forms that the user is able to click through.  In the main program I have a while loop that will keep looping through the forms and will initiate the form depending on which button the user pressed in the previous form (variable is called traverse).  Right now I put in an exit button on each form that will break the while loop.  What I'm having trouble with is when the user presses the red X at the top right corner, the form will not close (will just keep reloading).  I put a ** next to the line of the code that I thought might help with the issue (but obviously did not).

```
    while (Program.exit != "exit")
    {
        **if (Application.Exit = true)
        {
            break
        } else 
          {
            if (Program.traverse == "form4")
            {
                Application.Run(new Form4());
            }
            if (Program.traverse == "form1")
            {
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
            if (Program.traverse == "form5")
            {
                Application.Run(new Form5());
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

Is there a way C# can detect when the user presses the red X to break out of the loop?

Comment: There is so much wrong with your code I wouldn't even know where to begin. You don't run forms, you *show* them. You only run your application, normally through a main window form (if its as windows forms application), that keeps the app alive as long as its open. There is no need of a loop whatsoever.

Comment: You say you are new to c#. I recommend you get a good book or tutorial on c# with a chapter in windows forms towards the end and start from chapter one. Don't run before you even know how to crawl.

Answer (score 2):

First: your approuch is totaly wrong.

Second: befor starting i am totally recommend to you read some books about `Windows Forms` technology or, what better about `Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)` technology. After this you will no ask so wired questions and will improve you development speed and qualty dramaticly.

Third: direct answer to you question:

in you Form code behind you can do next:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Closed += OnClosed;
        }

        private void OnClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // DO, what you need when windows closed
        }

    }
```

Comment: So typically you run all the subsequent windows forms from your main one?

Comment: basicly - yes. Each application, *usually*, but not always, has only one main form/window, which create another by demand. ut again, it's depends from you architecure. And function `Application.Run` should be called only once in 99.99% cases (if you not create really difficult and complexivity app like Visual Studio).